# AdSense ad unit within Angular ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ads, adsense

I have two AdSense ad units on my website. First one is located directly in index.html and it is working perfectly. Another one is located in index.html also, but by a reference, like this:

`<aside class="right" ng-include src="'/app/components/right/right.html'">`

Everything under right.html is loaded normally and it works, expect AdSense ad unit, it is showing blank only.

What is the problem?